# Open Data for software options

Tags: data-request, uses-of-open-data

I need a dataset of the following:

1. user's software options for a particular software (e.g., whether to start the software with system) with
2. user's information (like user's system information, demographics).

The purpose is given a new user, based on the user's information, I can recommend them appropriate software options.

Is there any of such dataset?